# get JSON object javascript

Tags: javascript, json, groovy

I have the Student.groovy class that hasMany Note.groovy
Student Class extend to User.groovy

I have a JavaScript function that takes as a parameter a list of notes in JSON.
The code below works.

```
$.each(data,function(key, value) {
   alert(value.note);
   alert(value.semester)   
});
```

But if I do **alert(value.student)**; me is returned **[object, object]** 
and when I put **alert(value.student.toSource());** It's shown **({class: "project.Student", id: 1})**
If I do **alert(value.student.name);** It's shown ***undefined***

Comment: Can you provide an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: there is no _.name_ on student, if that toSource() is accurate

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely not sending back the correct `JSON format` to access the `student's name.`

As of now with the examples you have given you can only access the `class` and `id` of a given student.

```
value.student.class //<-- project.student
value.student.id //<-- 1
```

To be able to access the student's name you would have to have an object like so:

```
{
  class: "project.Student",
  id: 1,
  name: "Example name"
}
```

If you think you are actually sending everything you need from the server just do a little `$(document.body).append(data);` or `console.log(data);` on your getJSON success callback so you can see clearly what you have.

I wouldn't be surpized if `value.name` works by the way. Depends on  your json structure.

Comment: Follows the JSON output [{"class":"project.Note","id":1,"student":{"class":"project.Student","id":3},"year":"2015","semester"
:1,"note":0.0}]
Thanks for the  answer.

Comment: I did, I was rendering the JSON in standard form in Grails, using only render obj as JSON. to create the JSON with the children we use custom converters. In my case JSON.use('deep'){ render obj as JSON } 
https://grails.org/wiki/converters%20reference

Comment: You still having issues on this problem?